# How to fix garbage values that are being pushed back into a vector<int>, when I push a string containing integers

Tags: c++, stl

EDIT :- How his question is different than [Getting a character from a string is returning an unexpected number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37560073/getting-a-character-from-a-string-is-returning-an-unexpected-number)

1. The technology specified there is C#, not c++.
2. The question associates list box, while mine was associating a vector, and string.

---

I am trying to push a string full of integers with the help of string iterator in my c++ integer vector (vector), but unfortunately when I push the de-referenced string, all I get are some garbage value being pushed in my vector.

I tried searching google for days. Alongside that, I've tried looking documentations, and I've also tried to force convert the de referenced string iterator using (int).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;




int main() {
    string str = "1234";
    vector<int> vec;

    for (string::iterator itr = str.begin(); itr != str.end(); ++itr){         
        vec.push_back(*itr);

    }
    for (vector<int>::iterator itr = vec.begin(); itr != vec.end();      
    ++itr) {
         cout << *itr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected output : 1234

---

Actual output : 49505152

Comment: `'1'` is not the same as `1`. For example, in ASCII, `'1' == 49`. Edit : Notice your output are sequential 2 digit numbers. 49, 50, 51 and 52.

Comment: Well, that explains a lot. Is there anyway to force fix this, i.e to retain the integer without converting it into ASCII values?

Comment: Brian has posted an answer including how to do that.

Comment: Close voters: It's not really a dupe, this is C++ and the dupe is C#

Comment: Yes please have a look into that, and thanks @Jabberwocky for the help.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Found a better dup

Comment: @NeelMishra You are right that the previous duplicate close was not exact. But nonetheless, it does have several actual duplicates on this site. I've updated the question to point to one of them. Note that having your question closed as a duplicate is not a bad thing. It happens all the time. Duplicates act as guide posts for others to find and participate in a single question.

Comment: Ya, no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing "garbage values", but rather the numerical values of the characters in the string. That is, because you are using an ASCII system like the vast majority of people, the value of the character `'1'` is 49, and so on. If you want to convert a digit character, such as `'1'`, to the *integer*, such as `1`, you need to subtract `'0'` (which would be 48 on your system).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer! Is there any alternative, won't subtracting zero every-time in my code make my code look ugly?

Comment: @NeelMishra what are you _actually_ trying to achieve? If you have a string `"1234"` and you want to transform this into a `vector<int>` containing the `int` values 1,2,3 and 4, then you need to substract `'0'`

Comment: @NeelMishra I don't know what you mean by "ugly", but normally, your code should not be littered with this conversion since you should only perform it at the point where "input" is converted into an internal representation.

Comment: @NeelMishra This answers how to actually implement the behavior you want. There's a general consensus that it is the best way of doing it for the general case. If you find it ugly, feel free to hide it in a function. Then you can do, for example `vec.push_back(char_to_int(*itr));`. But `x - '0'` is a well known idiom in c++. Experienced developers will immediately recognize the pattern for what it is.